# Back up Ubuntu 22.04 into Synology

Tags: 22.04, backup, nas

I want to do a full backup of Ubuntu 22.04.01 on my [DS218 Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS218). I will like to do a full backup, with the possibility to have a single version or multiple versions. Also the most important is the possibility of encrypting or not the backup. Where I can find a such solution?

Best,
Andrew

Comment: You've given no clues as to what issue/problem you're trying to solve, I opened the link you gave and quickly saw it has a number of options available (NFS, SaMBa..) thus you can backup to it using whatever application (or strategy) you decide to use.

Comment: Nice post guiverc, and love the links. I will check them out.

Comment: @guiverc, my bad I will give more information on it.
I can access the Synology NAS using the NFS. I mount the drive on the ubuntu and that it is. From there I will need a solution/program to back up the Ubuntu 22.04.01 to Synology using NFS